# Setting color of padding for GtkAlignment

Tags: gtk

I have a `GtkTextView` inside a `GtkAlignment`, which I'm using to add top/bottom padding to the text view:

```
GtkAlignment
  top-padding: 5
  bottom-padding: 5
  child: GtkTextView
```

Right now it looks like this:

[image: GtkTextView with padding]

So, it works, but the padding is gray and I want it to be white (ideally I want it to be “the color of the text view” in case the user has a custom theme, but white would do as well). Is there any way to do it?

Comment: You could try setting the `textview` (or is it `textview.view`?) class on the alignment's style context.

Comment: What happens if you set 'margin-top' 'margin-bottom', or 'bottom-margin' 'top-margin' on the GtjTextView instead to create your extra white area?

Comment: @StianSkjelstad: it works, but the created margin is gray as well. (Besides, it has to be *padding*, not margin.)

Comment: @andlabs: could you give an example?

Comment: In C: `gtk_style_context_add_class(gtk_widget_get_style_context(theAdjustment), "textview");`

Comment: Did this work for you?

Comment: @andlabs Sorry for the wait! No, it didn't work (neither with `textview` nor with `textview.view`).

Comment: Interesting; I'll play around with this myself when I can and see what I can come up with.

Comment: How about `gtk_style_context_add_class(gtk_widget_get_style_context(theAdjustment), "GtkTextView");`? It's a 3.18-3.20 difference here; what I gave was for 3.20.

Comment: @andlabs nope, it doesn't work either (and I use 3.20 anyway)